# NLTK FreqDist, plot the normalised counts?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, normalization, probability

In NLTK, you can easily compute the counts for the words in a text, say, by doing

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
fd = FreqDist([word for word in text.split()])
```

where text is a string.
Now, you can plot the distribution as

```
fd.plot()
```

and that will give you a nice line plot with the counts for each word. In the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist.plot) there is no mention of a way to plot the actual frequencies instead, which you can see in `fd.freq(x)`.

Any straightforward way to plot the normalised counts, without taking the data into other data structures, normalising and plotting separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update **fd[word]** with **fd[word] / total**

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

text = "This is an example . This is test . example is for freq dist ."
fd = FreqDist([word for word in text.split()])

total = fd.N()
for word in fd:
    fd[word] /= float(total)

fd.plot()
```

NOTE : You will lose original FreqDist values.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon the lack of documentation. In `nltk`, `FreqDist` provides you with the raw counts (i.e. frequencies of words) in the text but `ProbDist` provides you with the probabilities of a word given a text.

For more information, you have to do some code reading: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py

The specific lines that do the normalization comes form https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L598

So to get a normalized `ProbDist`, you can do the following:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist
>>> from nltk.probability import DictionaryProbDist
>>> brown_freqdist = FreqDist(brown.words())
# Cast the frequency distribution into probabilities
>>> brown_probdist = DictionaryProbDist(brown_freqdist)
# Something strange in NLTK to note though
# When asking for probabilities in a ProbDist without
# normalization, it looks it returns the count instead...
>>> brown_freqdist['said']
1943
>>> brown_probdist.prob('said')
1943
>>> brown_probdist.logprob('said')
10.924070185585345
>>> brown_probdist = DictionaryProbDist(brown_freqdist, normalize=True)
>>> brown_probdist.logprob('said')
-9.223104921442907
>>> brown_probdist.prob('said')
0.0016732805599763002
```

Comment: Thanks. Too bad it doesn't have a plot() method to show a plot as FreqDist does though. Plus, FreqDist already has a `freq` method which normalises but this doesn't solve my problem of plotting directly from the object.

Comment: It might make little sense to plot probabilities, what's your x- and y- axes in that case?

Comment: Instead of the count I want the frequency of occurrence, that's all. Makes sense, I want to know what's the share of a word in a corpus. I understand the word "frequency" in linguistics is used to mean counts, but I'd like the ratio.

Comment: From a practical perspective, normalization without any smoothing, wouldn't your plot look exactly the same except for the scale? Let's say my vocabulary of the corpus is `the, hungry, eats` and the count is `100, 30, 50` respectively. And the probabilities would be `100/180, 30/180, 50/180` and if you plot the counts and probabilities on a histogram with words in your vocab as the x-axis and probabilities as the y-axis and you sorted them from highest prob to lowest, wouldn't you get the same point as words as x-axis and counts as y-axis (just that the scale is different on the y-axis) ? ;P

Comment: An important question to ask is `What are you normalizing against?`. If it's just sum count of all tokens, then the plot of frequencies vs normalized probabilities should look almost the same.

Comment: Yes, looks exactly the same but I have a different info on the y axis, which is what I'd be looking for. So, normalization by the total sum count of all tokens. I can do manually of course, was wondering why the `plot()` method doesn't seem to have this built in.

Comment: Try `plot.ly` (https://plot.ly/).  Format the probdist key-values to plot.ly and you can get cleaner and more beautiful graphs =)

Comment: Thanks, as I said I know how to plot what I want, was just looking for something built-in in the NLTK method for consistency/speed of process.

Comment: It makes sense for conditional frequencies/probabilities. Consider building a ConditionalFreqDist of `(language, word)` pairs from Wikipedia data. Something like `('en', 'the')` would probably dominate all others not only because of the prevalence of 'the', but because there are many more English articles than most other languages. Languages with fewer articles would appear as short scribbles at the bottom of the chart. If we want to plot the most frequent words per language, it makes sense to normalize these to a percentage so we can see all languages.